# Django Model QuerySet Group By Specific Fields

Tags: django, django-models, django-queryset, django-orm

Considering this model & data:

Ad_id + Date = primary key

```
    Ad_id  date   clicks
------------------------------
      3     8/10/12   124
      3     7/10/12   433
      3     6/10/12    99
      4     8/10/12    23
      4     7/10/12    80
```

I'm trying to group by ad_id to return the sum of the over all clicks.

in sql terms:

```
select Ad_id, date, sum(clicks) from ads group by Ad_id
```

The problem is the Django automatically do the group by for each field in the model, so the group by is not really working (because each row is unique).

**Solutions I've already checked:**

---

I know it is possible to do something like this:

```
Ad.objects.values('ad_id').annotate(clicks_sum=Sum('clicks'))
```

But it is not good as it doesn't return the Ad Model, but a dictionary.

I can't use also raw SQL because it is not chain-able

Also I tried to set

```
MyQuerySet.group_by = ['ad_id']
```

Not working too..

So I really need to group by only by the fields I need, and that the result will be an Ad Model.

Comment: Seems the `Ad_id` is not the primary key of the model, please post the model as is. Also, you can not select fields such as `date` w/o having it listed in `GROUP BY`

Comment: @okm I updated the model. about the date: in MySql it is possible to run this query (it's new to me too). but it is not really the issue here.

Answer (score 2):

You can perform raw SQL queries using `Manager.raw()`, in your case that would be:

```
Ad.objects.raw('select Ad_id, date, sum(clicks) from ads group by Ad_id')
```

This method method takes a raw SQL query, executes it, and returns a `RawQuerySet` instance. This `RawQuerySet` instance can be iterated over just like an normal `QuerySet` to provide object instances.

Comment: it can be iterated, but it is not chain able. I cannot do: Ad.objects.raw('...').filter(...)....